# Results from extensions and variations of Dixon's Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

The following problem\s stem from my investigations regarding an obscure identity discovered by Sir Alfred Cardew Dixon of Cambridge, it can be considered a theorem or formula, it's just silly sematics really because the essence of the concepts for which stem into modular arithmetic and number theory are captured in the equality as stated:

$$\sum_{k=-a}^{a}(-1)^k{2a\choose k+a}^3=\frac{(3a!)}{a!^3}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\operatorname{(Definition-1.0)}$$

note also I think at a prior date at some point I recall covering material written on the Riemann Zeta function by this fellow that was incredibly insightful albiet above my calibre at this point. none the less I will link the article for the identity above [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity).

A parameterization of the identity, that does not enumerate at any $m$     value to the actual identity, does however give credence to an aforementioned theorem in modular arithmetic:

$$\xi \left( n,m \right) =\sum_{k=-m n}^{m n}{(-1)^k\Bigl(\frac{(m n)!}{(k+n)!((m -1)n-k)!}\Bigr)^{m+1}}-\frac{((m +1)n)!}{(n!)^{m+1}}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\operatorname{(Definition0.0)}$$

The first lemma for which I found signficant concerning $\xi \left( n,m \right)$ is that the difference in  the integer remainders of the divisions of $\xi \left( n,m \right)$ by any two consecutive natural numbers $(v,v+1)$ is a constant as follows:

$$\Bigl(\frac{\xi \left( n,m \right)}{v}-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\xi \left( n,m \right)}{v}\Bigr\rfloor\Bigr)v -\Bigl(\frac{\xi \left( n,m \right)}{v+1}-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\xi \left( n,m \right)}{v+1}\Bigr\rfloor\Bigr)(v+1)=\frac{(n(m+1))!}{n!^{m+1}}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\operatorname{(Lemma0.1)}$$

The second, which brings us to a more clear picture as to why $(0.1)$ is so, is that the *sign* of  $\xi \left( n,m \right)$ is periodic, and the beauty in the simplicity of $(0.1)$ is really only appreciated when taking a look at just how painful in relational complexity this periodicity is, for which the signs that result from this in effect can be seen as the reason for which the *constancy* of $(0.1)$ exists, (or to put another way, independance of size of the integer remainders of division by $(v,v+1)$ for which the difference of is equal to the same constant for a given fixed $(n,m)$ ) which i have done my utmost to attempt to simplify as much as I can, I have chosen to represent some components of the sign identity in terms of the Kronecker delta function as denoted by $\delta(x,y)$, however as one will see from it's contents what is being stated can just as easily be stated as congruence relations as we are familar in the form $a\equiv b\pmod n$, however I have chosen to represent the components of the sign identiy with dependance in $n$ with the former, and those components with $m$ dependance with the latter. If you have issue with my use of notation for this instance I will be happy to discuss alternatives with a serious individual  with a  non satirical stack exchange account:

$$\frac{\xi \left( n,m \right)}{|\xi \left( n,m \right)|} =\cases{ \left( -1 \right) ^{1-\delta(\frac{n}{4}, \lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor) }&$m\equiv 1\pmod 2 \land m\not\equiv 2\pmod 4
$\cr  \left( -1 \right)^{1-\delta(\frac{n}{2},\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)}&$m\equiv 0\pmod 2 \land m\not\equiv 2\pmod 4
$\cr 1&$m\equiv 2\pmod 4$\cr}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\operatorname{(Lemma0.2)}$$

So to summarise thus far, this question is a request for assistance in
establishing a rigorous proof for:

1)  the periodicity of $(0.0)$ as defined by $(0.2)$,

2) and the constancy of $(0.1)$ which results.

I have gone into further details about this subject but I don't want to carry on and receive a critical response for my question being too large, so I would like to leave it here i think for now.

I currently feel that induction could be applied to what I have already established but I just never feel comfortable unless it is applied to a circumstance that involves a vanishing quantity, anyway happy thanks giving pilgrims